# Should Exceptions handle returning Error Responses

Tags: laravel, exception

I created and API and implemented various custom exceptions. It seems like Exceptions can render a response to the user. So my controller methods can either return a response, or throw a custom exception, which in turn returns an error response (see below):

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try {
        $myModel = MyModel::find($id);
        if ($myModel !== null) {
            $service = new ModelService($sequence);
            if($service->destroyModel())
                return $this->deleteSuccess($sequence);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Could not find Model.', 404);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        throw new DeleteModelException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }
    //this path is never reached, function technically has path that doesn't return
}
```

Technically, I have a path that returns nothing, but `DeleteModelException` handles the rest of it.

Is this good practice or should I just keep the error responses within the controller? Not sure why the base `Exception` (`Illuminate\Foundation\Exception`) class would allow for rendering responses if not for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend the practice of throwing custom and descriptive exceptions and let the exception's render method return the response for you.

When the project gets larger and you track the exceptions with application observing tool such as [`sentry`](https://sentry.io/welcome/) for example, these exceptions will help a lot to know whats happening in the project.

I would do :

```
public function something(){

    try{
        // actions
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        throw new \SomethingFailedExeption('Faild to do something');
    }
}
```

And then create a class `App\Exceptions\SomethingFailedExeption`

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SomethingFailedExeption extends Exception
{
    /**
     * Render the exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $this->getMessage(),
            'somefield' -> $request->somefield
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

Also I would recommend `FindorFail(`) instead of `Find()` so that laravel throws  the exception for you

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. Also thanks for the suggestion about `find()`.